# How to upgrade angular version from 7 to 8?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-upgrade

Running `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` I would get this every time

> Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency
>   to "@angular/compiler" (requires "8.2.0-next.1", would install
>   "8.1.1")   Package "ag-grid-angular" has an incompatible peer
>   dependency to "@angular/compiler-cli" (requires ">=2.1.x" (extended),
>   would install "8.2.0-next.1").
>
> Package "angular-calendar" has an incompatible peer dependency to
>   "@angular/core" (requires ">=5.0.0 <7.0.0" (extended), would install
>   "8.1.1").
>
> Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency
>   to "@angular/compiler" (requires "8.2.0-next.1" (extended), would
>   install "8.1.1").
>
> Package "angular-calendar" has an incompatible peer dependency to
>   "@angular/common" (requires ">=5.0.0 <7.0.0" (extended), would install
>   "8.1.1").
>
> Package "angular-calendar" has an incompatible peer dependency to
>   "@angular/animations" (requires ">=5.0.0 <7.0.0" (extended), would
>   install "8.1.1").

My Environment now is :

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 12.6.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.12.4
@angular-devkit/core               7.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.9
@angular/animations                7.2.15
@angular/cdk                       7.3.7
@angular/cli                       7.3.9
@angular/material                  7.2.0
@angular/material-moment-adapter   7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                   7.2.4
@schematics/angular                7.3.9
@schematics/update                 0.13.9
rxjs                               6.5.2
typescript                         3.4.5
webpack                            4.28.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to run this command:

```
ng update --all --force
```

This sort of updates all applicable Angular packages.

As for the other 3rd party packages such as `angular-calendar`, you may need to manually run the npm command to update them to the versions that supports Angular 8.

When it comes to checking your 3rd party packages, you can simply run the command and it will return the list of latest versions for those packages.

```
npm outdated
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should follow the steps mentioned in the update guide
https://update.angular.io/.

Also, when receiving errors such as yours, you might want to prefix the commands with `--force`, like

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli --force
```